# Cannot find JDK '<unknown>' for module 'appcompatV7'

Tags: java, android

I have this error popping up.

***Error:java: Cannot find JDK '' for module 'appcompatV7'***

I cant work out why its happening, im using compatibility library and added it in the project structure. Selected it as "Library module" and added as module dependency.

Its working fine on another project with exactly the same set up.

Comment: What JDK are you using? List the steps you used to add the appcompat library into your project. Maybe you're missing something along the way.

Comment: Ive got 1.7.0_02 version
I select "Project Structure" in Android Studio, Modules -> Add -> Import Module -> Select it. Once its one I click on main project and add "appcompatV7" in export table + "libs". I have all my 

Module SDK for appcompatV7 is API16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution. I restarted Android Studio and messaged popped up saying, "Error loading project: cannot load 2 modules" within android.iml file, suggested i remove it, then recompiled and it worked. Thanks for the ideas guys!

Answer (score 0):

JDK v7 won't work as the `appcompat` libraries are compiled against Java v6, so you'll need JDK v1.6.45.

You can download the JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR).

Install the JDK and try again.

Comment: That could work, but im at work and most of the downloads are blocked! Found solution, android.iml was causing the problem

Comment: Please note that JDK v7 currently is not supported by Android.